# ioio open accessory doesn't work, while adb works

Tags: android, adb, accessory, ioio

I'm able to get my application working when I have USB debugging on. But when I turn of debugging so I can use open accessory, the application doesn't work. What happens is that when I connect the IOIO to the phone I am asked to choose an app to run, and when I select an app that is supposed to blink a led, nothing happens. 
The led blinks when I have usb debugging on.
What could be the problem and what should I do to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps your phone doesn't support OpenAccessory. What make/model of phone is it and what version of Android?